# Webpack in ES6 create an empty bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use webpack in ES6 but there is something wrong, the bundle is created but it seems to contain nothing.

src/index.js

```js
console.log("inside");
export const testData = 15;
```

webpack.prod.js

```js
import path from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";

export default {
    entry: {
        myApp: './src/index.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Production',
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(".", './dist'),
        clean: true,
        module: true,
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
                include: path.resolve(".", "src")
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: "production",
    devtool: "source-map"
};
```

package.json

```json
{
 ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.5.0",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "5.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.8.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1"
  },
  "type": "module"
...
```

After creating the bundle, the `index.html` file inside the `dist` folder I insert a log but when it starts does not show the log and gives me the error `testData is not defined`

dist/index.html

````html
...
<head>
    <title>Production</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="myApp.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            console.log( "window load" );
            console.log( "testData" );
            console.log( testData ); // <--------------------- it give the error
        }, false)
    </script>
</head>
...```
````

Comment: *"but it seems to contain nothing"* Have you looked at the content of `myApp.bundle.js` directly? *"but when it starts does not show the log and gives me the error testData is not defined"* Accessing `testData` outside the module will not work. `testData` doesn't magically become a global variable. Look at the [`output.library` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are exporting const value, which get disolve in build and webpack optimization process. It's better to make it part of some module and export it.
With few modifications you can get what you are expecting.

###### index.js

```
export default {
    fuel: 100,
    passengers: 7,
    target: 'mars',
    launch: function () {
        console.log('Saturn VI ready to launch');
    },
    reportPorblem: function () {
        return 'Houston, we have a problem';
    },
    land: function () {
        console.log('Saturn VI landed successfully')
    }
};
```

Remove `module: true` from output, what it is you can learn [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputmodule).

##### output.library

Also you need to make few to changes to output in webpack. Remove `libraryTarget` and add `library` to output.
With library name here it's `MyLibrary` you can access exported details. Type property set how module to be exposed, webpack allow you to expose your module with certain standards with `libraryTarget` or `library.type`. Here its expected to be `var`.

###### webpack.prod.js

```
output: {
    ...
    library: {
        name: 'MyLibrary',
        type: 'var',
        export: 'default',
    },
},
```

There are quite few options supported by webpack.

1. libraryTarget: "umd", *enum*
2. libraryTarget: "umd-module", *ES2015 module wrapped in UMD*
3. libraryTarget: "commonjs-module", *ES2015 module wrapped in CommonJS*
4. libraryTarget: "commonjs2", *exported with module.exports*
5. libraryTarget: "commonjs", *exported as properties to exports*
6. libraryTarget: "amd", *defined with AMD defined method*
7. libraryTarget: "this", *property set on this*
8. libraryTarget: "var", *variable defined in root scope*

You can learn more about libraryTarget [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget)

So finally you can access all you wanted from library `MyLibrary`.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        const mySpaceShip = MyLibrary;
        console.log(`Traveling to ${MyLibrary.target} with ${MyLibrary.crewmates} crewmates`)
    }, false)
</script>
```